# Why does chrome throw "Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8" here?

Tags: javascript, onload, domexception, yahoo-analytics

Below is the code for my YWA wrapper

```
var astr_ywascript = (document.createElement("script").type = "text/javascript").src = "http://d.yimg.com/mi/eu/ywa.js";
document.head.appendChild(astr_ywascript); // <- error on this line
```

It's run on page load, so it makes no sense that JS can't find the document head tag.

Any ideas?

Thanks

---

Opera throws this error on the same line. `Uncaught exception: Error: WRONG_ARGUMENTS_ER`
Firebug says: `document.head is undefined [Break On This Error] document.head.appendChild(astr_ywascript);`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the line

```
(document.createElement("script").type = "text/javascript").src
```

you are setting the src property of a string. The assignment in parentheses returns the assigned value. You make the same mistake later in the line, ultimately assigning `"http://d.yimg.com/mi/eu/ywa.js"` to `astr_ywascript`

Split it out onto separate lines:

```
var el=document.createElement("script");
el.type="text/javascript"
el.src=...
document.head.appendChild(el);
```

Raw Javascript rarely behaves in the fluid way one gets used to with jQuery.

You might also want to get the head as follows:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]
```

Answer (score 8):

I got this error with Backbone.js because I was doing:

```
$('#backbone').html(@view.render())
```

Instead of

```
$('#backbone').html(@view.render().el)
```

Like I should have done. Still don't really know what this 'el' business is, but I'm sure I'll figure it out soon.

Comment: .el is Backbone's reference to the element that gets updated by render(). You probably have `return this;` in your render() method, which returns a reference to the Backbone View itself, when it sounds like you were expecting `return this.el` which would let you do `$(...).html(@view.render())`

Comment: This comment just solved a MASSIVE headache for me! I'd be interested to know why the convention is to do 'return this' from the render function rather than returning this.el?

Comment: I was getting the same problem when passing an array to .append() function. Instead of passing simple html text I passed **an array** of html text and that made the issue happen.

Answer (score 0):

Just appending this answer for people who might hit this page like I did while searching for an answer to a `“Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8` error.

I had this error in Chrome.  In my case I was using `.appendChild(ttt);`

The issue was that `ttt` was an array object instead of the div I intended to append.

So make sure what you are appending is actually a DOM object and not accidentally a different object type.